# Picking a specific point of a map in Direct 3D

Tags: directx9

I'm trying to pick a specific point on a randomly generated terrain with bunch of tiny triangles. Right now, I'm just iterating through every triangle and picking a intersected triangle using D3DXIntersect function. It serves its function but the performance is just not tolerable.

Is there a way to pick a triangle without millions of iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how the triangles are created? If you have access to that, you could choose a random triangle at creation and store that. I don't see a reason you should need to use the GPU or DirectX for this task unless they are sent to the GPU in code you don't have access to.